# How do I create a global OnClick event in Flash AS2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a Flash AS2 application that is made up of many SWF files. I need to create an OnClick event in a container SWF that will work for every SWF called. I am trying to avoid adding code to every SWF (over 100).

Currently I can get access to the click in the container for the first SWF but when the second SWF is called it seems to overwrite the container.

```
this._lockroot = true;

this.onMouseUp = function(){
    //if not on login
    getURL("javascript:clickTest();");
};

//load swf
loadMovie("test.swf","_level2");
```

How do I make where a click in the container will be triggered even if the SWF inside the container calls another SWF?

This seemed so simple but has been a nightmare. Is it even possible?

Comment: Is that the code in the clips being loaded, or the code in the container?  Just for clarification, you've got one container, which loads any of >100 other clips, which then in turn load other clips?  Or do the >100 clips load each other in sequence (after the first has been loaded by your container)?

Comment: The original did not have a container. I just added it to hold the code above. The SWF contained in the container have links that load other SWF files based on what the user is doing.

Comment: I think once the contained SWF calls another SWF the container goes away. I do not know how to have the container remain through the calls to other SWF files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit (re: comments, onClipEvent shenanigans didn't work)**

How about trying something like this:

```
this.createEmptyMovieClip("holder", this.getNextHighestDepth());
loadMovie("test.swf","holder");
```

instead of:

```
//load swf
loadMovie("test.swf","_level2");
```

Or, if _level2 is necessary to the structure of the app, something like this:

```
_level2.createEmptyMovieClip("holder", _level2.getNextHighestDepth());
_level2.holder.loadMovie("test.swf");
```

I just tried this out with a 2-level nested load, and it maintained the click handler in the top level (while using a loadMovie w/o the holder didn't).  I'm not sure if the assumptions I made match the structure of your nested SWFs, but that's my best guess at this point.

Comment: The problem is not that the code does not work with the click event it is the problem of the click event persisting after a new swf is called by the embedded swf.

Comment: what's the code that the loaded SWFs are using to load other SWFs?

Comment: they are using loadMovie too.

Answer (score 0):

You could have movieClip named e.g. `clickHaver` on top layer (at all costs) - if second movie (and each next) loads the next movie into itself:

```
- container
  - loads movie.swf
    - loads movie2.swf
```

then your only concern is to keep `clickHaver` on top after loading the first movie, since every next loads another `.swf` file in itself.